# Haskell: how to map a tuple?

Tags: haskell, mapping, tuples

In Haskell, I can easily map a list:

```
map (\x -> 2*x) [1,2]
```

gives me `[2,4]`. Is there any "mapTuple" function which would work like that?

```
mapTuple (\x -> 2*x) (1,2)
```

with the result being `(2,4)`.

Comment: BTW, no need to use lambdas to map a simple multiplication over a list: simply `map (*2) [1,2,3]` would do the trick.

Comment: Note that no matter how you implement this, it will only work on tuples with the type: (a, a)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[Searching at Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%20-%3E%20b%29%20-%3E%20%28a,%20a%29%20-%3E%20%28b,%20b%29) gives no exact matches for `(a -> b) -> (a, a) -> (b, b)`, which is the type you require, but it is pretty easy to do yourself:

```
mapTuple :: (a -> b) -> (a, a) -> (b, b)
mapTuple f (a1, a2) = (f a1, f a2)
```

Note, you will have to define a new function for 3-tuples, 4-tuples etc - although such a need might be a sign, that you are not using tuples like they were intended: In general, tuples hold values of different types, so wanting to apply a single function to all values is not very common.

Comment: `Control.Arrow` *is* in the standard libs, and `Control.Bifunctor` istn't too far away...

Comment: @Landei: Yes, but the OP asked about mapping a single function over a tuple.

Comment: @Landei: I removed the mention of the standard libraries, since I don't know much about which modules are in them, or are going to be soon, and just mentioned hoogle, which was where I searched.

Comment: You can always use the Applicative trick to feed an argument twice in a function: `(bimap <$> id <*> id) (*2) (3,5)`

Answer (score 91):

Here's a rather short point-free solution:

```
import Control.Monad (join)
import Control.Arrow ((***))

mapTuple = join (***)
```

Comment: What is the effect of join when used on functions?

Comment: @Riccardo - `join` takes a function of two arguments with the same type, `a->a->b`, and creates a new function with one argument `a -> b`, passing that argument to both positions of the original function.  This is because the Monad instance for functions is identical to the `Reader` monad, giving `join` type `(a -> a -> b) -> a -> b`.  I find it a little easier to work out when the arrows aren't written infix, e.g. `join :: (a ->) ( (a ->) b) -> (a ->) b`.

Answer (score 36):

You could use `Bifunctor`:

```
import Control.Monad  (join)
import Data.Bifunctor (bimap)

join bimap (2*) (1,2)
```

This works not only for pairs, but for a number of other types as well, e.g. for `Either`.

`Bifunctor` is in [base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html) as of version 4.8. Previously it was provided by the [bifunctors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-4.1.1/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html) package.

Comment: The `join` trick for the `(->)` monad instance is awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! That beats what I found in another context, where I just wanted to modify the second value, i.e. import`Data.Graph.Inductive.Query.Monad` and then `(*2) >< (*2)` is the function you're after. (I'm puzzled that this isn't in Data.Tuple, but perhaps that's just an accident of history.)

Answer (score 25):

You can also use [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) to map tuples:

```
import Control.Lens
mapPair = over both
```

Or you can map over tuples with upto 10 elements:

```
mapNtuple f = traverseOf each (return . f)
```

Comment: `over each` seems to work too: `(over each) (+1) (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) == (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`

Answer (score 24):

You can use [arrows](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows) from module `Control.Arrow` to compose functions that work on tuples.

```
Prelude Control.Arrow> let f = (*2) *** (*2)
Prelude Control.Arrow> f (1,2)
(2,4)
Prelude Control.Arrow> let f' = (*2) *** (*3)
Prelude Control.Arrow> f (2,2)
(4,4)
Prelude Control.Arrow> f' (2,2)
(4,6)
```

Your mapTuple then becomes

```
mapTuple f = f *** f
```

If with your question you asked for a function that maps over tuples of arbitrary arity, then I'm afraid you can't because they would have different types (e.g. the tuple types `(a,b)` and `(a,b,c)` are totally different and unrelated).

Comment: Do I need to load a module to use them? In plain Prelude your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 16):

Here is another way:

```
mapPair :: (a -> b) -> (a, a) -> (b, b) -- this is the inferred type
mapPair f = uncurry ((,) `on` f)
```

You need `Data.Function` imported for `on` function.

Comment: I think this is the simplest and most elegant solution. +1

Comment: This only works for a tuple-2. It solves OP's problem, but isn't applicable to tuples of arbitrary sizes.

Answer (score 13):

To add another solution to this colourful set... You can also map over arbitrary n-tuples using [Scrap-Your-Boilerplate generic programming](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scrap_your_boilerplate). For example:

```
import Data.Data
import Data.Generics.Aliases

double :: Int -> Int
double = (*2)

tuple :: (Int, Int, Int, Int)
tuple = gmapT (mkT double) (1,2,3,4)
```

Note that the explicit type annotations are important, as SYB selects the fields by type. If one makes one tuple element type `Float`, for example, it wouldn't be doubled anymore.

Comment: I understand vaguely that a lot of the original SYB libraries have been replaced by GHC Generics with some support in base/compiler. (But maybe you and that wikipedia page use "SYB" ad a term for generics in general, and not just the specific original SYB papers... )

Comment: I might be wrong, but given that GHC's [`Data.Data` documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Data.html) cites SYB, I'd wager that it's a direct descendant.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, for tuples of 2 items, you can use [`first`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html#v:first) and [`second`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html#v:second) to map the contents of a tuple (Don't worry about the type signature; `a b c` can be read as `b -> c` in this situation). For larger tuples, you should consider using a data structure and lenses instead.

Answer (score 9):

The [extra](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra) package provides the [`both`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-0.8/docs/Data-Tuple-Extra.html#v:both) function in the [Data.Tuple.Extra](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-0.8/docs/Data-Tuple-Extra.html) module. From the docs:

```
Apply a single function to both components of a pair.

> both succ (1,2) == (2,3)

both :: (a -> b) -> (a, a) -> (b, b)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use Applicatives which have additional benefit of giving you possibility to apply different functions for each tuple element:

```
import Control.Applicative

mapTuple :: (a -> a') -> (b -> b') -> (a, b) -> (a', b')
mapTuple f g = (,) <$>  f . fst <*> g . snd
```

Inline version:

```
(\f -> (,) <$>  f . fst <*> f . snd) (*2) (3, 4)
```

or with different map functions and without lambda:

```
(,) <$> (*2) . fst <*> (*7) . snd $ (3, 4)
```

---

Other possibility would be to use Arrows:

```
import Control.Arrow

(+2) . fst &&& (+2) . snd $ (2, 3)
```

Answer (score 5):

I just added a package [tuples-homogenous-h98](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuples-homogenous-h98) to Hackage that solves this problem. It adds `newtype` wrappers for tuples and defines `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Foldable` and `Traversable` instances for them. Using the package you can do things like:

```
untuple2 . fmap (2 *) . Tuple2 $ (1, 2)
```

or zip tuples like:

```
Tuple2 ((+ 1), (*2)) <*> Tuple2 (1, 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

The [uniplate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate) package provides the [descend](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate-1.6.12/docs/Data-Generics-Uniplate-Operations.html#v:descend) function in the [Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate-1.6.12/docs/Data-Generics-Uniplate-Data.html) module. This function will apply the function everywhere the types match, so can be applied to lists, tuples, Either, or most other data types. Some examples:

```
descend (\x -> 2*x) (1,2) == (2,4)
descend (\x -> 2*x) (1,"test",Just 2) == (2,"test",Just 4)
descend (\x -> 2*x) (1,2,3,4,5) == (2,4,6,8,10)
descend (\x -> 2*x) [1,2,3,4,5] == [2,4,6,8,10]
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you would do:

```
map (\x -> (fst x *2, snd x *2)) [(1,2)]
```

`fst` grabs the first data entry in a tuple, and `snd` grabs the second; so, the line of code says "take a tuple, and return another tuple with the first and second items double the previous."

Comment: Your code does not work, but as a side note remember that you can pattern match at the arguments to a lambda function: `\(x,y) -> (x*2,y*2)`

Comment: @danr - I was missing a parenthesis, thanks for pointing it out :P. I wasn't aware of pattern matching though, thanks!

Comment: I don't see any reason to use `map` on a list with a single element: the point here is the function in the parentheses in fact.