# Haskell: how to map a function over an arbitrary tuple of monads

Tags: haskell, tuples, monads, functor, haskell-lens

Is it possible to construct a function that will map of a tuple of monads of arbitrary arity?

E.g.,

```
f :: (m a -> m [a]) -> (m x, m y) -> (m [x], m [y])
```

(but for arbitrary arity). [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722689/haskell-how-to-map-a-tuple), has a number of promising suggestions; e.g., lens' `each` or `over both`, but each seem to require a tuple of homogenous types: I want to use a tuple of homogenous monads with differing inner types.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible in the way that you're saying.

In your type signature, the initial function can only take an `m a`, but you expect to pass it an `m x` and an `m y`, so the types don't match.

It's certainly possible to do it with `rankNTypes` enabled:

```
{-# LANGUAGE rankNTypes #-}
f :: Monad m => (forall a. m a -> m [a]) -> (m x, m y) -> (m [x], m [y])
f fun (x, y) = (fun x, fun y)
```

This is because `forall a.` inside the brackets forces it to be polymorphic, rather than just for a type `a`.

---

What you're probably wanting is something like this:

```
f :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (m a, m a) -> (m b, m b)
```

or even

```
f :: Monad m => (a -> m c) -> (b -> m d) -> (m a, m b) -> (m c, m d)
```

Note that I changed the function type from `m a -> m b` to `a -> m b` because that allows us to sequence monadic actions, rather than transform the monad, which makes more sense when we want to manipulate them.

Comment: Okay, thanks @AJFarmer.   I feared it couldn't be done,  but couldn't explicitly reason why; so figured it's worth asking,  if only to clarify why not.  The key seems to be that the fn passed as first arg is pinned down to a single specific a at instantiation time,  unless we use rankNTypes as you say.

Comment: @user3416536 that's right; type variables are carried across a function's type, and it's not implicit that two types with different variables are equal, but it's possible. `forall` just says that it can work on any type, which, of course, includes `m x` and `m y`!