# Create List by multiplying object with [1..n]

Tags: list, haskell

I am still not into Haskell and need a hint for the following function.

I want to create a list by adding each multiplication of a pair:

```
all :: Int -> (Int,Int) -> [(Int, Int)] 
all n, pair = ...
```

E.g. n = 3, pair (1,2) => [(1,2), (2,4), (3,6)]
which expands to [(1*(1,2)), ((2*(1,2)), (3*(1,2))]

I know its something with `x <- [1..n]` and `x*pair` but I don't know which built-in function is right to put it together!

Comment: http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension

Comment: yes that's the hint I needed! I was looking into map and stuff :D

Comment: `all n pair = ...` is a better starting point and then perhaps you may use `map f [1..n]` with a proper `f`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the multiplication separately on the elements in the tuples, and then recreate a tuple. You can use `fst` and `snd` to get the elements.

```
all n pair = [(x*(fst pair), x*(snd pair)) | x <- [1..n]]
```

Pattern matching is another common way to access tuple elements.

```
all n (a, b) = [(x*a, x*b) | x <- [1..n]]
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, there are other ways to map to a tuple: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722689/haskell-how-to-map-a-tuple

Comment: @Lorenzo That's true, thanks for pointing it out. `both` from the extra package seems to do it. But I think it's good practice for beginners to solve this themselves.

Comment: it's much nicer (imo, but pretty sure almost every Haskell developer would agree) to pattern match on the pair rather than using `fst` and `snd`