# Create an array of all possible variations of a triple in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am a newby to Haskell and I am trying to create a function that takes a triple and returns an array of triples, like so:

```
tripleVariations 1 (0,0,0)
=> [(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)]
```

I understand how to match to a specific value in the triple with pattern matching and I even created a custom function that maps a function over a triple, but I don't understand how to replace one value of the triple, add that to the array and *then* continue to the next value in the triple. I find that I tend to try and solve these problems too much according to imperative paradigm, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Surely you can just write it? `tripleVariations w (x,y,z) = [(w,y,z), (x,w,z), (x,y,w)]`?

Comment: I am literally facepalming by how simple the solution is, so thank you very much for that! I just wonder if that isn't too much "hardcoding" things, or is this very normal in functional paradigm? Thanks again!

Comment: No, I think "normal in functional programming" is to make a function that can work on any size tuple. But why bother?

Comment: Don't abstract for its own sake; abstract if it makes your code simpler.

Comment: Already posted this to the published answer, but: I assumed that I simplified the problem that I am trying to solve in such a way that it still is usable for the eventual solution, but now I worry that I do need a bit more in debt information: I actually need to be able to check a condition when adding the eventual triple to the array, so, i.e., only replace when the initial value is 0 would result in: `tripleVariations 1 (0,0,2)=> [(1,0,2), (0,1,2)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely you can just write it:

```
tripleVariations w (x,y,z) = [(w,y,z), (x,w,z), (x,y,w)]
```

If you wanted this to work with *any* size tuples, it would be more complicated... but you don't, so why waste the effort?.

According to [Haskell: how to map a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722689/haskell-how-to-map-a-tuple) *there is no way to iterate over a tuple* because tuples can have diferent types in them. It wouldn't make sense to iterate over the type `(Int, String, Char)` for example. If you want to write code that works with tuples where every part has the same type, presumably you should use a list instead of a tuple.

Comment: I assumed that I simplified the problem that I am trying to solve in such a way that it still is usable for the eventual solution, but now I worry that I do need a bit more in debt information: I actually need to be able to check a condition when adding the eventual triple to the array, so, i.e., only replace when the initial value is 0 would result in: 
`tripleVariations 1 (0,0,2)=> [(1,0,2), (0,1,2)]`

Comment: @ovda96 Updated. I suspect it is impossible without simply writing out the whole code, because you cannot iterate over  tuples. (Well, you could write your own function to iterate over tuples)

Comment: @ovda96 A standard trick for building a 0-or-1-length list is to use comprehension syntax. For example, if your predicate for checking whether a particular spot should be substituted is named `p`, you can write `[(w,y,z) | p x] ++ [(x,w,z) | p y] ++ [(x,y,w) | p z]`.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWagner! I am however trying to adapt this to a list in the end, so I will post a new question :).